# SpringBoot Starter Project - Error resolving template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-boot-test

I am writing a JUnit test, which should test the title of an html page. This project is a SpringBoot, Thymeleaf starter project.

HtmlPath:

```
private final static String HTML_PATH = "/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html";
```

JUnitTest:

```
@Test
public void shouldRenderPageTitle() throws IOException, NodeSelectorException {
    Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    model.put("pageTitle", "expected title");
    HtmlElements tags = testEngine.process(HTML_PATH, model);
    assertThat(tags.matching("title"), isSingleElementThat(hasOnlyText("expected title")));
}
```

ThymeleafConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new TemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringStandardDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

The Error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html"
```

[image: Dir tree]

Comment: `private final static String HTML_PATH = "pages/dashboard/dashboard.html";`?

Comment: I have tried this approach with no luck

Comment: try without `.html`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use
    private final static String HTML_PATH = "/pages/dashboard/dashboard";  //no ".html"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing this line of code

```
templateResolver.setPrefix("/resources/templates/");
```

with this one

```
templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
```